# How to add country and state in wooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added the custom country and state field in the vendor registration form in WooCommerce.Successfully inserted data in the database. But data showing as a short of form, like country is PK and state is PK-21. How to show the full form ? like Pakistan instead of PK and Karachi city instead of KR-21. I used following code for country and state.I want to show like this https://prnt.sc/LCBhi-FxwruZ in the user edit section from dashboard.I know that is not big deal. Just i can't catch the issues. Any one can help me how to fix this issues.

```
<?php
$field = [
'type' => 'country',
'label' => 'Country',
'required' => 1,
'class' => ['address-field']
];
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country', $field, '' );
$field = [
'type' => 'state',
'label' => 'State',
'required' => 1,
'class' => ['address-field'],
'validate' => ['state']
];
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_state', $field, '' );
```